# JavaScript sorting and grouping items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I am trying to do some mapping in JavaScript. What I am trying to do is I am trying to check if the type from `arr` exists in `datasetarr`, if existed, I get the index in `datasetarr` and increment the quantity of that index. If not exists, I add in a new entry in `datasetarr`. Here is my code:

```
var datasetarr = [];
var pos;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    console.log('unsorted ' + arr[i].type + ' ' + arr[i].quantity);
    if(datasetarr.indexOf(arr[i].type) > -1){
        pos = datasetarr.indexOf(arr[i].type);
        datasetarr[pos].quantity += arr[i].quantity;
    }else{
        datasetarr.push({type: arr[i].type, quantity: arr[i].quantity});
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < datasetarr.length; i++){
    console.log('sorted ' + datasetarr[i].type + ' ' + datasetarr[i].quantity);
}
```

The output should be:

```
kitchen appliance 20
home entertainment 8
batteries & lightings 4
home appliance 12
```

Then, I can get the type and quantity each and store into array for me to plot with chart.

However, with my code above, the things that I am getting is exactly the same as the unsorted one. Any ideas which part of my logic went wrong?

Comment: It would easier to help you if you replace the image with the actual array (as code)..

Comment: If you could add some useful code, like `array A`, `array B`, and `datasetarr` would be easier. Or even better, a working example in fiddle, snippet or similar.

Comment: Edited question with arr and proper naming convention instead of array A/B

Comment: So basically you want to group array `arr` by `type` and sum `quantity` values? (and output result in `datasetarr`)

Comment: @gmo Yeah that is what I am trying to achieve. Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use objects for the grouping.

```
var categories = {};

function incrementBy(category, value) {
  if (!categories[category]) {
    categories[category] = 0;
  }
  categories[category] += value;
}

var datasetarr = [];
var pos;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log('unsorted ' + arr[i].type + ' ' + arr[i].quantity);
  incrementBy(arr[i].type, arr[i].quantity)
}

for(var category in categories){
  console.log('sorted ' + category + ' ' + categories[category]);
}
```

You can decompose the object if needed, through it into an array and sort it if required.

A little bit cleaner example, which might let you follow along a little bite better:

```
var arr = [{type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 3},
    {type: 'batteries & lightings', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'home appliance', quantity: 5},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 4},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 5},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 3},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 4},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 1},
    {type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 1},
    {type: 'home appliance', quantity: 5},
    {type: 'batteries & lightings', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 2},
    {type: 'home appliance', quantity: 2}];


function group(array) {
    var categories = {};

    function incrementBy(category, value) {
        if (!categories[category]) {
            categories[category] = 0;
        }
        categories[category] += value;
    }

    array.forEach(function (value, index, arr) {
        incrementBy(value.type, value.quantity)
    });

    return categories;
}

function print(categories) {
    for (var category in categories) {
        console.log('%s: %s', category, categories[category]);
    }
}

print(group(arr));
```

Here a solution of of `group` hiding the grouping, which than can hold your own implementation:

```
function group(array) {
    var categories = {};

    function incrementBy(object) {
        var category = categories[object.type];
        if (!category) {
            category = categories[object.type] = {};
        }
        var subCategory = category[object.subType];
        if (!subCategory) {
            subCategory = category[object.subType] = {};
        }
        subCategory += object.value;
    }

    array.forEach(function (value, index, arr) {
        incrementBy(value, value.quantity)
    });

    return categories;
}
```

Depending on your use case, you could also flatten the structure:

```
function incrementBy(object) {
    var key = [object.type, object.subType].join('/');
    var category = categories[key];
    if (!category) {
        category = categories[key] = {};
    }
    subCategory += object.value;
}
```

But it might make sense to have various maps in place:

```
function groupings(array) {
    var groupings = {
      types: {},
      subTypes: {},
      paths: {}
    };

    function incrementBy(object) {
        var category = groupings['types'][object.type];
        if (!category) {
            category = groupings['types'][object.type] = {};
        }
        category += object.value;

        var subCategory = groupings['subTypes'][object.subType];
        if (!subCategory) {
            subCategory = groupings['subTypes'][object.subType] = {};
        }
        subCategory += object.value;


        var key = [object.type, object.subType].join('/');
        var path = groupings['paths'][key];
        if (!path) {
            path = groupings['paths'][key] = {};
        }
        path += object.value;
    }

    array.forEach(function (value, index, arr) {
        incrementBy(value, value.quantity)
    });

    return categories;
}
```

To avoid information loss on aggregations, you could simply create a more complex data structure:

```
function groupByAndSumBy(data, groupByProperty, sumByProperty) {
  var accumulator = {};

  data.forEach(function(object, index, array) {
      var localAcc = accumulator[groupByProperty]
            = accumulator[groupByProperty] || { items: [] };
      localAcc[sumByProperty]
            = (localAcc[sumByProperty] || 0) + object[sumByProperty];
      localAcc.items.push(object);
  });

  return accumulator;
}

function groupByMerchantNameAndSumByTotalSales(data) {
    return groupByAndSumBy(data, 'merchantName', 'totalSales');
}
```

This creates an aggregation which also contains the subset of the input array, which allows you a more detailed view on the data.

Comment: Where you declare the categories? inside both the function for incrementBy and the for loop function there?

Comment: A `category` is basically `arr[i].type`. So it is defined only what the method is called.

Comment: Sorry but what I meant is the code above is two separate functions right? The two for loop in one function and the incrementBy as another function. Both of them using the categories object, so I declared the object in both of the function. But somehow it is not printing anything for now.

Comment: I added a more extensive example. I hope it helps to follow along a little bit better.

Comment: Hey sorry but just to check with you, let's say now I have 3 attribute, for instance, subtype, quantity and product name. By any chance, by grouping the same subtype to calculate the quantity, can I bind the product name to the subtype as well? As in the product name need not to be sorted, it is just an extra attribute that should binded with subtype

Comment: I added a couple more examples, which illustrate different solutions ... as I am not clear if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much! But let's say for cases like I got merchantName, branchName, branchAddress & totalSales. I wanted to sum up the totalSales together according to branchName. This can be achieved from the first solution you provided. But after sorting right, I am only left with branchName & totalSales. Is there any way to get the merchantName & branchAddress as well? 1 branchName belongs to 1 merchantName & 1 branchAddress only, therefore we can ignore them for sorting purpose.

Comment: I added an example, which preserves the original items in an extra array. The `branchName` is the bucket for the data, `totalSales` an accumulated value and `items` contains all elements which are used to calculate `totalSales` for the given `branchName`, a real subset of the input data.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd suggest [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for this kind of stuff

```
result = _(arr)
    .groupBy('type')
    .mapValues(xs => _.sumBy(xs, 'quantity'))
    .value();
```

In this particular case, however, a vanilla JS solution is just as easy:

```
let result = {};

for (let item of arr)
    result[item.type] = (result[item.type] || 0) + item.quantity;
```

Comment: This question is not tagged [tag:lodash] or [tag:ecmascript-6], but if you're going to use ES6, you might as well `for (let { type, quantity } of arr)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: as of 2017, I guess it's safe to assume ES6 for `javascript` questions by default.

Comment: I disagree. If the asker is using ES5 (`var` is a big tip-off, in addition to using no ES6 features), the general consensus is to answer with ES5. I upvoted your answer regardless, as I think using lodash is convenient, but I was mainly giving you advice to improve your ES6 answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is because, Your If condition is only checking for index value in the resulted array **datasetarr** which is already empty for next value to be pushed,

So Your

```
        if(datasetarr.indexOf(arr[i].type) > -1){
        pos = datasetarr.indexOf(arr[i].type);
        datasetarr[pos].quantity += arr[i].quantity;
    }
```

will never execute.
That is the reason you are getting the same output as input.

Comment: Hmm so how should I fix it?

Comment: Rather in place of **if** loop call a function to push only **distinct** categories to the resultant array **datasetarr** and keep on adding the quantity in the same in each call to the function.
Or you want me to write the logic for you ??

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generalized aggregate function like this, and call it by specifying the keys that categorize and aggregate, which are `type` and `quantity` respectively. Lastly, you specify the `reducer` function, which is just an aggregate sum, `a + b`:

```js
function aggregate (array, predicate, value, reducer) {
  // group values by predicate
  var groups = array.reduce(function (groups, item) {
    if (item[predicate] in groups) {
      groups[item[predicate]].push(item[value])
    } else {
      groups[item[predicate]] = [item[value]]
    }

    return groups
  }, {})

  // aggregate each group of values by reducer
  return Object.keys(groups).map(function (group) {
    var summary = {}
    summary[predicate] = group
    summary[value] = groups[group].reduce(reducer, 0)
    return summary
  })
}

// input array
var arr = [{ type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 3 }, { type: 'batteries & lightings', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'home appliance', quantity: 5 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 4 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 5 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 3 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 4 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 1 }, { type: 'home entertainment', quantity: 1 }, { type: 'home appliance', quantity: 5 }, { type: 'batteries & lightings', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'kitchen appliance', quantity: 2 }, { type: 'home appliance', quantity: 2 }]

// output array
var sums = aggregate(arr, 'type', 'quantity', function (a, b) { return a + b })

// formatting
var output = sums.map(function (item) {
  return item.type + ' ' + item.quantity
})

// string output
console.log(output.join('\n'))
```

Comment: I see but is there any way to get the type and quantity from output? Like for instance output.type or output.quantity? because I will be using them to plot for the chart. So far for now the output is formed as a string right

Comment: I just showed you how, it's in the last two statements... and you did state that was your desired output format, so if that's not what you want, you should have said what you required in the first place.

Comment: As in I wanted to get all the type from output and store into a temp array, and all the quantity from output and store into another temp array. Then I will be using these two temp arrays to plot for charts. Currently the output itself is formed as a string so output.type, output.quantity returns me undefined

Comment: @EmmaHannah please read the comments in the code. The aggregate array you want is in `sums`, the output of `aggregate()` as I've explained multiple times now. The formatted string lines are in output, as requested within the question.

Answer (score -1):

Based on OP question:

> I am tryin to check if the type from arr exist in datasetarr, if existed, I get the index in datasetarr and increment the quantity of that index. If not exists, I add in a new entry in datasetarr.

And the clarification in comments:

> Q: So basically you want to group array arr by type and sum quantity values? (and output result in datasetarr)
>   A: Yeah that is what I am trying to achieve.

I think the best and easy way to do it is doing exactly that, check if exist and act accordingly.

```
var datasetarr = [];
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (datasetarr.hasOwnProperty(arr[i]["type"])) {
    // exist -> increment
    datasetarr[arr[i]["type"]] = datasetarr[arr[i]["type"]] + arr[i]["quantity"];
  } else {
    // no exist -> add new
    datasetarr[arr[i]["type"]] = arr[i]["quantity"];
  }
}
```

Expected output for `datasetarr` variable would be:

```
datasetarr = {
    "batteries & lightings" => 4,
    "home appliance" => 12,
    "home entertainment" => 8,
    "kitchen appliance" => 21
];
```