# Grouping array of objects and doing a calculation to create a new common value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, aggregate, lodash

I'm using lodash to group my objects in my array.

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(this.tableData, function(obj) {
  return obj.key
});
```

It's giving me an object with key value pairs.

```
{mykey1: [{obj1}, {obj2}], mykey2: [obj1]}
```

My question is how can I loop through the objects inside each key and do a calculation. for example if I have an attribute in my object, `cost`, I want to sum up all the cost inside each object in my key?

Comment: Looks like you want `_.mapValues(grouped, group => ....)`. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410237/javascript-sorting-and-grouping-items-in-array/45410783#45410783

Comment: `var grouped:any = _(this.tableData).groupBy(this.tableData, function(obj) {
                return obj.key
            }).mapValues(xs => {
                
            });`

Comment: tried, getting errro, supplied params do not match the ..... error

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `_.mapValues` and `_.sumBy`:

```
var summed = _.mapValues(grouped, function(v){
    return _.sumBy(v, 'cost');
});
```

Live example below:

```js
var tableData = [
{key:"obj1",cost:1},
{key:"obj1",cost:1},
{key:"obj1",cost:1},
{key:"obj2",cost:1},
{key:"obj2",cost:1}
]

var grouped = _.groupBy(tableData, function(obj) {
    return obj.key
});

var summed = _.mapValues(grouped, function(v){
    return _.sumBy(v, 'cost');
});
console.log(summed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could use `_.sumBy(v, 'cost')`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks - im more familiar with vanilla javascript than lodash/underscore methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could do native javascript:

```
//let obj = {key1: [{cost: 1}, {cost: 2}], key2: [{cost: 3}]}; example input
Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, arr)=> sum + arr.reduce((subsum, element)=>subsum + element.cost, 0), 0);
```

Explain:

```
Object.values(obj) //-> [[{cost: 1}, {cost: 2}], [{cost: 3}]]
[1, 2, 3].reduce((sum, element)=> sum + element), 0) //-> reduce (converting a list of things into one)
```